# python: function to return a list without a given element

Tags: python

I'm familiar with `list.remove`, which will mutate a list by deleting the first instance of the passed element, raising a value error if the element is not present.

What I'm looking for is a function that does not mutate the list, but rather returns a copy of the list without the given element.  So, for instance, instead of executing

```
l = [1,2,3]
l.remove(2)
```

I would execute

```
l = [1,2,3].remove(2)
```

The purpose of this is to make it a bit simpler to put this type of logic into a dict definition.  So that rather than:

```
l = [1,2,3]
l.remove(2)
d = {
  'theList': l
}
```

I just have

```
d = {
  'theList': [1,2,3].remove(2)
}
```

Does such a function exist?

Note that I want to remove only the first instance of the value in question, not all instances, so `[x for x in [1,2,3] if x != 2]` does not do what I want.  Though I'm not sure if there is a list comprehension way to do this.

Comment: Are the answers really any improvement on the complexity of your code?

Comment: @roganjosh well, it could prevent an unnecessary local variable, for instance, which my linter is complaining about.

Comment: I have a feeling they're slower than your current approach, double indexing a list and then concatenating the results, for example. Or copying the whole list. I'm not sure I would trust the linter here, but I'd want it timed. And, IMO, there's no readability to be gained.

Answer (score 4):

Such a method does not exist for the `list` type.

Although, you can write it yourself by copying the list first, removing the element and returning the new list.

### Code

```
def remove(lst, el):
    new_lst = lst.copy()
    new_lst.remove(el)
    return new_lst
```

### Example

```
>>> l=[1,2,3]
>>> remove(l, 2)
[1, 3]
>>> l
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: @Aran-Fey I can replace "neat" by "interesting" if that pleases you

Comment: copy remove is much better than the itertools & the indexing solution. Doesn't get any clearer.

Comment: @Aran-Fey Since it is around 4-5 times slower, I'll plain remove it

Answer (score 3):

You can use `index`:

```
a = [1,2,3]
{'a': a[:a.index(2)] + a[a.index(2)+1:]}
```

or as function:

```
def remove(a, e):
    idx = a.index(e)
    return a[:idx] + a[idx+1:]
```

Answer (score -2):

Could you do:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3]

def remove(l, i):
    r = l[:]
    r.remove(i)
    return r

>>> remove(lst, 2)
[1, 3]
>>> lst 
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: list.remove returns None, not the list.